# Fortran: Array of unknown size in type

Tags: arrays, types, fortran

Perhaps this is a really stupid question and one should really do this differently, but:
Is there a possibility to have something like

```
type food
 INTEGER :: NBananasLeft(NBananaTypes)
 INTEGER :: NApplesLeft(NAppleTypes)
end type food
```

where NBananaTypes and NAppleTypes is not known at compilation time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fortran 90-95:

```
type food
 INTEGER,pointer :: NBananasLeft(:)
 INTEGER,pointer :: NApplesLeft(:)
end type food
```

you must allocate the arrays yourself using `allocate(var%NBananasLeft(NBananaTypes)))`.

In Fortran 2003:

```
type food
 INTEGER,allocatable :: NBananasLeft(:)
 INTEGER,allocatable :: NApplesLeft(:)
end type food
```

you must also allocate the arrays yourself using `allocate(var%NBananasLeft(NBananaTypes)))`, but you avoid the possibility of memory leaks.

In Fortran 2003 by parametrized data types (only a few compilers support that):

```
type food(NBananaTypes,NAppleTypes)
 integer,len :: NBananaTypes,NAppleTypes
 INTEGER :: NBananasLeft(NBananaTypes)
 INTEGER :: NApplesLeft(NAppleTypes)
end type food
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, that I have to write a function, like: type(food) makeFood(NBananaTypes, NAppleTpyes, NBananasLeft, NApplesLeft), where I allocate makeFood%NapplesLeft and makeFood%NBananasLeft and then say makeFood%NapplesLeft=NApplesLeft,..

Comment: More or less yes. You can also use an intrinsic constructor with the Fortran 2003 automatic reallocation (I believe it should work, but correct me if not).

Comment: If you agree with the answer, you can (and after some time probably should) accept it by clicking on the green tick on the left. This also applies to your previous questions.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Didn't know - I am as new to Fortran programming as to stack exchange...

Comment: @user1638145: I often use this type of "constructor" function to hide allocation of dynamic type components or to do something more elaborate than simply assigning values. You can also have an `interface food` to interface any number of such functions with the same name as your derived type. This allows transparently creating objects as `bar = food(NBananaTypes, NAppleTypes)` or with any other signature you specify.

Comment: Actually I couldn't get this to work, but it might have been my fault, doing something else wrong. I ended up giving the arrays predefined sizes and throwing an error if the size got too big

Comment: This is strange, just `type(food)::var` and `allocate(var%NBananasLeft(NBananaTypes)))` with the second or first definition of food above should really work.

Comment: Why the second option avoid the possibility of memory leaks? Don't you also need to deallocate it manually ?

Comment: No, in Fortran 95 all allocatables are deallocated automatically when going out of scope.