# fortran derived type with parameterized len

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, derived-types

I found this question/answer
[Fortran: Array of unknown size in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090715/fortran-array-of-unknown-size-in-type), which demonstrates fortran derived type with parameterized len.

```
type food(NBananaTypes,NAppleTypes)
 integer,len :: NBananaTypes,NAppleTypes
 INTEGER :: NBananasLeft(NBananaTypes)
 INTEGER :: NApplesLeft(NAppleTypes)
end type food
```

I would really like to use this feature of the standard. Which compilers will actually let you do this? gfortran [does not](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OOP#Unimplemented_features).

Comment: I believe that both the Cray and IBM XL Fortran compilers already implement this feature.  See http://www.polyhedron.com/compare0html for further information.

Comment: that is an interesting link, but I don't see the parameterized derived types information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status of new standards implementation is regularly published in Fortran Forum. The latest version is http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2460236.2460238 . You can see somwhat older version at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status which says you can use PGI, IBM or Cray compilers. From these three the only available for PC computers is the PGI. I also checked the recent version of the report and it does not add anything new.

Comment: Just for posterity, you mean IBM, not intel. Anyway, thanks for the wiki link. PGI it is.